# VLC can't load .srt files

Tags: 15.04, vlc

After an update of VLC media player, it became unable to add `.srt` subtitle files. When I run it in the terminal and try to add a subtitle file, it outputs `core stream error: cannot pre fill buffer`.

I've already tried reinstalling.

I'm running VLC 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: This sounds very much like some sort of bug to me, I would suggest reporting it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+filebug) or by running `ubuntu-bug vlc`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help but I had a lot of problems with VLC after a fresh installation.

I found the answer on my own which is documented there [Full mess on VLC after fresh installation - ubuntu 14.04](http://bit.ly/1hey4ER)

Hope this could help you